# What's the best dialog plugin ( jquery based )?

Tags: jquery, dialog, plugins

I used to use jquery's native ui dialog plugin, felt a bit bloated to me. I'm looking for something lighter. Any suggestions? What I'm trying to get from a dialog plugin is that it can help popup panel like interface which allows dragging and resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) is pretty sweet